# Why don't these JavaScript toggles work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://kaytee.karmathemes.com/shortcodes/fullwidth-columns/

Note the toggles on the page, clicking on them doesn't produce an action, one day they just stopped working, does anyone have any idea why?

Comment: You need to include the relevant code here in your question or else we can't really evaluate your problem.

Comment: Which toggles exactly do you mean? Btw, you have some script errors on your page, please fix them first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onload="setTheDivStyle()"` is not defined apparently.

Also `jSwing` is not defined either so i"m assuming a jQuery plugin isn't being loaded.